# Differences in behavior between Chrome and Safari for ES2022 private static methods

Tags: javascript

The following JavaScript code will work in both Safari and Chrome, but with different results.
I would like to know why this is happening.

```
<script>
class Bar {
    'use strict';
    baz() {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            resolve();
        }).then(() => {
            return [2];
        });
    }
}
new class {
    'use strict';
    #foo = 1;
    constructor() {
        console.log(this.#foo); // 1
        (new Bar()).baz()
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);   // [2]
                console.log(this.#foo); // 1
                [this.#foo] = res;
                console.log(this.#foo); //*** Chrome: 2, Safari: 1 ***
            });
    }
}
</script>
```

Note that if you declare #foo as foo instead of private static methods, the final result will be 2 for both.

Chrome 97.0.4692.99
Safari 15.3 (17612.4.9.1.5)
macOS Monterey Ver. 12.2
MacBook Air (M1,2020)

afterwards:
I heard that it will be fixed in the next version.
https://webkit.org/blog/12193/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-139/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the described behavior and to reduce the code to this:

```js
(() => new class {
    #foo = 1;
    constructor() {
        [this.#foo] = [2];
        console.log(this.#foo); //*** Chrome: 2, Safari: 1 ***
    }
})();
```

This looks pretty much like a bug in JavaScriptCore/Safari.